# error in my code java practical for i showin int[]

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class prac22{

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println("ENter the no of elements:");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int len = input.nextInt();

        int arra[] = new int[len];

        System.out.println("Enter the element:");
        for (int i=0;i<len;i++) {
            arra[i] = input.nextInt();
            
        }

        int count=0;
        for (int i=0;i<arra;i++ ) {
            if(arra[i] == 9) {
                count++;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Total number of 9 in array" + count);
    }
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
what is this error means

prac22.java:20: error: bad operand types for binary operator '<'
for (int i=0;i<arra;i++ ) {
^
first type:  int
second type: int[]
1 error

Comment: adding on to what scary wombat said, you are comparing `i` an int with arra a "box" of int. You dont want the box of ints but you want how many ints there are inside the box. so you call arra.length

Answer (score 0):

Either loop using the length

```
for (int i=0;i<arra.length;i++ ) {
```

or using a for-each

```
for (int i : arra) {
    if(i == 9)
```